# App script error Please select an active sheet first. (line 4, file "Code")

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting an error `Please select an active sheet first. (line 4, file "Code")` when trying to publish my apps script dashboard app based on [this](https://github.com/gkaldevrel/charts-in-apps-script) tutorial. I've read through some other posts about setting an active sheet but it only produced more errors. I'm at a loss as to how to correct this. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
function doGet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<sheetid>');
  var data = ss.getDataRange();

  var ageFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(1).build();
  var nameFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(0).build();
  var genderFilter = Charts.newStringFilter().setFilterColumnIndex(2).build();

  var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
                   .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().set([0,1,2]))
                   .build();

  var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
                   .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition().set([0,,2]))
                   .build();

  var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel().setDataTable(data)
                   .bind([ageFilter,nameFilter,genderFilter], [tableChart, pieChart])
                   .build();

  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var filterPanel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var chartPanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  filterPanel.add(ageFilter).add(nameFilter).add(genderFilter).setSpacing(10);
  chartPanel.add(tableChart).add(pieChart).setSpacing(10);

  dashboard.add(app.createVerticalPanel().add(filterPanel).add(chartPanel));
  app.add(dashboard);
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<sheetid>');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheetNameHere');///////Need to get the sheet, not just the whole work book.
var data = sheet.getDataRange();
```

Comment: What if I do not want to specify sheet name and want to get the first sheet.

Comment: var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];